# Help что значит role="full-horizontal"?

Tags: html5

Help что значит role="full-horizontal"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Атрибут role](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-role/) используется чтобы указать определенный тип: горизонтальное меню (full-horizontal), выпадающий список (select), ниспадающее меню (custom-dropdown) и canvas.

Вот, [почитайте](http://habrahabr.ru/post/159359/).

Answer (score 2):

Вечер добрый. Атрибут **role** предназначен для пояснения роли того или иного блока. В XHTML значение атрибута обычно выбирается из определенного словаря ([словари по умолчанию](http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab)). Здесь же, судя по всему, просто используется произвольное значение.